# Ruby Using each_slice.to_a

Tags: ruby, each

I'm trying to subdivide an array into pairs of arrays.

For example: `["A","B","C","D"]` should become `[["A","B"],["C","D"]`.

I believe I've succeeded by doing `arg.each_slice(2).to_a`. 
But if I were then to do `arg.length` on the new array I still get 4.
I expect to get 2 (in the above example).

In the end, I want to be able to call the first element of `arg` to be `["A","B"]` but at the moment, I am still getting `"A"`.

Comment: What was the exact code you were using? `[1, 2, 3, 4].each_slice(2).to_a.length` gets me 2 back.  Are you reassigning the values?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
array = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

array
 => ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

array.each_slice(2).to_a
 => [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]

array.each_slice(2).to_a.length
 => 2
```

Maybe you are expecting that `array.each_slice(2).to_a` will change your original `array`, but here you will have new `Array` object, because `each_slice` is non-destructive method, like most in ruby.

```
new_array = array.each_slice(2).to_a
new_array
 => [["A", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
new_array[0]
 => ["A", "B"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and helpful response. I was able to determine my mistake quickly with your help.

Comment: Would be great if you could put some of the answer into the question as an edit.  This has ~700 views and is quite confusing as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
arg = arg.each_slice(2).to_a
```

In ruby methods that change state of there instances usually has  `!`at the end. For example

```
hash1.merge!(hash2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
1.9.2p180 :015 > ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].each_slice(2).to_a[0]
```

=> ["A", "B"]

works fine